# Strip method for non-whitespace characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Is there a Ruby/Rails function that will strip a string of a certain user-defined character? For example if I wanted to strip my string of quotation marks "... text... "

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html#M000942

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I'm reinventing the wheel here so if you find a built-in method that does the same, please let me know :-)

I added the following to `config/initializers/string.rb` , which add the `trim`, `ltrim` and `rtrim` methods to the String class.

```
# in config/initializers/string.rb
class String
  def trim(str=nil)
    return self.ltrim(str).rtrim(str)
  end

  def ltrim(str=nil)
    if (!str)
      return self.lstrip
    else
      escape = Regexp.escape(str)
    end

    return self.gsub(/^#{escape}+/, "")
  end

  def rtrim(str=nil)
    if (!str)
      return self.rstrip
    else
      escape = Regexp.escape(str)
    end

    return self.gsub(/#{escape}+$/, "")
  end
end
```

and I use it like this:

`"... hello ...".trim(".")` => " hello "

and

`"\"hello\"".trim("\"")` => "hello"

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use tr with the second argument as a blank string. For example:

```
%("... text... ").tr('"', '')
```

would remove all the double quotes.

Although if you are using this function to sanitize your input or output then it will probably not be effective at preventing SQL injection or Cross Site Scripting attacks. For HTML you are better off using the gem sanitize or the view helper function `h`.

Comment: But I only want to replace the " at the start and end of my string/text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one out of the box, but this should do what you want:

```
class String
  def strip_str(str)
    gsub(/^#{str}|#{str}$/, '')
  end
end

a = '"Hey, there are some extraneous quotes in this here "String"."'
puts a.strip_str('"') # -> Hey, there are some extraneous quotes in this here "String".
```

Comment: Note that `^` and `$` match the start and end of line.  You want `\A` and `\z` to match the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use String#gsub:

```
%("... text... ").gsub(/\A"+|"+\Z/,'')
```

Comment: That should actually be a lowercase `\z`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class String
    # Treats str as array of char
  def stripc(str)
    out = self.dup
    while str.each_byte.any?{|c| c == out[0]}
        out.slice! 0
    end
    while str.each_byte.any?{|c| c == out[-1]}
        out.slice! -1
    end
    out
  end
end
```

Chuck's answer needs some `+` signs if you want to remove *all* extra instances of his string pattern. And it doesn't work if you want to remove any of a set of characters that might appear in any order.

For instance, if we want a string to not end with any of the following: `a, b, c`, and our string is `fooabacab`, we need something stronger like the code I've supplied above.